# GDB Quirks with Thread Process

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I am debugging a process with multiple threads in GDB. I compiled the sole source file with the `-g` flag. However, while running in GDB, the following scenario occurs:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb7fe2b70 (LWP 2604)]
0x00000011 in ?? ()
```

Prior to the switch, the particular thread executes a `sleep(5);`

Why can't GDB identify the point from which the code "segfaulted"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x00000011 is not a valid address, especially not for code. This tells us, that there is no code (thus no function) at 0x00000011. And this tells us, that your stack is corrupted.
Without a "working" stack, gdb is unable to figure out how your thread ended up where is has, because it does not log any calls by default and hence relies solely on the stack.

**EDIT**
Note that on x86 you will end up with similar behavior as you've described by code like

```
_start:
   mov eax,0x11
   jmp eax
```

This leads to a jump/branch to a region (0x11) where there's no code and consequently no debugging symbols neither. This might happen in a case like in my example, but also if the stack is overridden (corrupted) and the returning jump leads to an invalid address (like 0x11)

Comment: Other threads' stacks might not be corrupted - view their backtraces using `thread apply all backtrace`. Whether that will be helpful in this case, I cannot say.